# Decrypting with OpenSSL gets bad decrypt ( C++ )

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I am currently using the AES-CBC-256 method to decrypt a simple test string that is encrypted using the same method via php openssl. The exact error I'm getting is as follows:

```
11324:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:.\crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:531:
```

The code being used to decrypt is the following:

```
void handleErrors(void)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;
    if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return plaintext_len;
}
```

I've heard this is caused by either incorrect padding, or trying to decrypt something generated by a different OpenSSL version, so I've kept both at 1.1.0h and allowed OpenSSL to use its default padding.

I don't think the decryption code is incorrect, as it was used to decrypt files with the appropriate key and iv fine. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seem to have gotten it, if anyone ends up having this issue.

Make sure you are writing your code with C in mind, even if you are using C++ for the key and iv generation. I copied the data from an std::string with no luck, but then shifted to a char (no middleman) with great results. Converting that to a unsigned char then yielded success